# Installing Ubuntu on a corrupt Dell Mini with Windows 7 without optical disk drive.

Tags: installation

I have a Dell Mini 10 with a corrupt Windows 7 OS (Bootmgr missing).

How can I install Ubuntu as it does not have an optical disk drive? Can I install from an USB stick?

Comment: Many thanks for the help, have now installed it just trying to get some details working now such as flash.

Comment: If one of the answers was instrumental in fixing your issue, please be sure to take the time to mark that answer as "accepted". Around here that's the best way to say "thanks for a good answer."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install from USB stick. Ubuntu installation will overwrite the bootmgr and make your computer just as fine (even better probably, since it's Ubuntu ;)) - given that this is the only problem with it.

Anyways. There are many ways to get Ubuntu on a USB stick, many of which are easy to find with google - or on the Ubuntu site it self.

I assume you are going to do this from another machine, probably a Windows machine? There is a great guide on the Ubuntu website explaining this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

```
To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick 
with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use 
the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. 
You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.
```

It is really as easy as that. When you are done making your USB stick, you just have to boot from the USB stick and follow the installation of Ubuntu.

If you are not on Windows, the same link has information about doing this from Ubuntu or Mac OS too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it from an USB stick. Read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). If you're on windows:

Download and use [Linux Live Usb Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download).

Once you have usb-creator.exe, run it and follow the same steps as described for Linux (point it at your .iso file or your Ubuntu CD-ROM, point it at your USB flash drive, make sure you have the right device selected, then "Make Startup Disk").

As Ubuntu doesn't use Windows bootmgr (it uses GRUB boot loader) you won't have any problems to boot Ubuntu, but maybe you will have to fix Window's bootmgr for booting into it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.